# How to set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES with python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to run code with python3 while using a specific GPU, but it seems like I can only choose the GPU when using v2 of python.

I am trying to use a specific GPU to run a program with the command

CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python3 program.py

However, it seems to not have any effect at all and just uses the first available GPU anyway. Yet when I switch to the older version of python by using

CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 python program.py

it seems to work as intended. How can I set my GPU but still run python3? I have tried workarounds  involving os.environ, but they also do not work.